# Как очистить LocalStorage в IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, localstorage

Пытаюсь найти ошибку в показе сайта в `IE11`, но для этого мне нужно посмотреть как всё выглядит когда пользователь впервые зашёл на сайт. И мне мешает `LS`, который уже запомнил многое и мешает мне это сделать. Собственно, как очистить `LS`? В интернете не нашёл ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызвать в консоли на своей странице

```
localStorage.clear()
```

не годится?

Comment: я видел это решение, но, честно, не совсем представляю как это делается, поскольку с консолью не работаю) ладно, попробую, спасибо

Comment: спасибо, всё просто оказалось